Composite not compositing images
I'm completely new to Blender, but I’ve started using it to camera track scenes and add objects into them.
All my nodes are correct as far as I can tell but when I hit render it only shows the movie clip. If I hit background or foreground I can see that it rendered the objects but they are not visible. I'm guessing it's something stupid since I'm so new to this. My composite nodes are render layer and movie clip each tied to a single alpha over node which is tied to the composite node.
I'm also only hitting render image because it’s taking so long to render one frame. I have a 3080 and Ryzen 7600x.


We can’t see your node set up unless you show us, and since you are having trouble understanding how it’s working, you might be describing it incorrectly. Please add screenshots.

if u wanna have quicker help instead of answering questions in the comments - i would recommend providing your blend file. I think because you are new to Blender you don't know which screenshots are important and which aren't.
